# How do you Integrate user data access control with oauth2.0 API's?

Tags: firebase, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to figure out how OAuth2.0 (or something else entirely) can be used to handle a situation where a user who is calling a backend api, can only retrieve data relevant to that user.

For example:
Lets say I have a bank application, and the customer account information is located at "bank.com/account/{customerId}". How do I restrict access to this, so that other customers cannot see each-others bank account information? As anyone with an access token could get anyone's account info and Roles can't solve this.

I have come up with a potential solution to this problem using Firebase JWTs which is to access the header of the incoming request and compare the User ID in the body of the token to that of the data being accessed.

My gut tells me I am missing the bigger picture, as this problem must be a common phenomena, and I could not find the answer elsewhere.

My Environment is a Spring Boot backend utilizing the Oauth2.0 resource server pointing to the firebase project. Backend is connected to a Postgres database. Frontend is an Angular Application.

Comment: To add to Jan's answer, all real world systems use claims for authorization, from the payload of the JWT. This [Curity article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/) explains the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure users can access only their own resources, you must write it in your Spring Boot application. OAuth2 only provides you an access token which you can use to find out who is calling you and what scopes he has granted.

But the security logic is up to you to implement. If you have a userId in URLs, you should check that it matches the userId from access token. If user data is stored in a database, you will probably need to add conditions to your SQL queries such as `WHERE user_id = :userId`.

You can also use scopes from an access token to grant only partial access to user's resources. It's useful if another application can access user's resources on his behalf. Such as reading person's name and email when logging in somewhere using Google/Facebook/Github.

Comment: The difference between the ID Token vs Access token was one of my main sources of confusion, now that I know that ID token != an Access token with a User ID claim, that clears things up (As I read ID tokens should not be used for Access). I will likely either try to implement this as a Cross Cutting Concern or something baked into Google's Api Gateway product since I am using Firebase. Will gladly take implementation recommendations for either.